# pthread read-write lock indefinite behaviour

Tags: c++, pthreads, readwritelock

I came across a unexpected results in test for pthread read-write lock.

the following is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>

//locks declaration
pthread_rwlock_t       rwlock;

//shared resource
int numbers[20];
int size = 0;


void readFrom()
{
    int rc;

    rc = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);

    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    std::cout << numbers[index] <<  " ";
    }    
    std::cout << std::endl;

    rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
}

void writeTo(int index, int val)
{
    int rc;

    rc = pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);

    numbers[index] = val;

    size++;

    rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc=0;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::thread threads[25];

    rc = pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock, NULL);

    for(int i=0; i<20; ++i) {
    threads[i] = std::thread(writeTo, i, i);
    if(i % 5 == 0) {
        threads[20 + (i / 5)] = std::thread(readFrom);
        }
    } 



    for(int i=0; i<24; ++i) {
    threads[i].join();

    }



    std::cout << "size is " << size << std::endl;


    threads[24] = std::thread(readFrom);
    threads[24].join();
    std::cout << std::endl;



    rc = pthread_rwlock_destroy(&rwlock);
    return 0;
}
```

after several runs, I occasionally find there are something unexpected. Here is an example:

0 1 2 3 0

It is a output from a reader thread. Basically, it says the size of numbers is 5 for now. in that case, I expect the result should be 0 1 2 3 4.

By the way, I have tried to implement addition mutually exclusive lock, which stoke unexpected behaviour.

I am interesting in the solution as well as the root cause. Could anyone help me out?

any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Your surprise seems to originate from the expectation that the writer-threads execute in order. Why exactly should they, in the absence of explicit synchronization to that effect?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think the result should be "0 1 2 3 4"? What specifically do you think prevents a result of "0 1 2 3 0"? (If you have four cores, that's exactly what I'd expect.)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. My CPU module is intel core™ i7-5500u processor. I check the intel specification online which claims the number of cores are 2. However, I have ’lscpu‘ executed, which shows there are 4 processors. I do not think this result make any sense.  In addition, I have made attempts to implement forced ordering with mutex, but as i mentioned, it worsens. I'd like to be fed :)

Comment: @Bill You have two physical cores and four virtual cores.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz could you please tell me why we should expect the result of "0 1 2 3 0". I am really confused by it even after looking into the specification of pthread_rwlock in pthread header.

Comment: @Bill A "fair" algorithm for the mutex gives cores the mutex in the order they requested it. First core outputs 0 now must wait its turn, second core outputs 1 now must wait its turn, third core outputs 2 now must wait its turn, fourth core outputs 3 now must wait its turn, first core now gets a turn and outputs 0 again ...

Answer (score 0):

A reader/writer lock just prevents two writers from running at the same time or a writer from running at the same time as a reader. Neither of those things are required to get the output "0 1 2 3 0". So there is no reason you should consider that unexpected.

In fact, if you have four cores, "0 1 2 3 0" is certainly an output that I'd expect at least some of the time. The threads run in the order they were started until all four cores are in use, then new threads have to wait until existing threads finish their timeslices. That seems perfectly reasonable to me.

If you can detail the thought process that made you think "0 1 2 3 0" is unexpected, we can point out the specific flaw in it.

By the way, for an application like this, you should just use a regular lock. Using a reader/writer lock only makes sense when reader operations significantly outnumber write operations or readers need to hold the lock for relatively long times.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate explanations for my doubts. As a matter of fact, this code is designed to serve the comparison purpose with my own implementation of read/write lock mechanism.